# Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition

Tags: visual-studio

I work for a relatively small company and with a change to our servers etc., I am being asked if Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition will work for me.

I mainly use Visual Studio to create and Deploy SSRS Reports, but I would like to have a 'full' version of Visual Studio rather than a 'limited', scaled back version - for other development [SSIS, SSAS, VB.Net] I do from time to time.

Is there a way to stick with VS Community, do I need an upgraded license such as VS Pro, or is there another option?

Answer (score 0):

According to this post, SSIS, SSAS and SSRS are now extensions, and you should be able to install extensions in the VS2019 Community Edition.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0a98a3af-91d0-4f00-8673-4ff53c12e738/how-to-use-ssrs-in-community-visual-studio-2019?forum=aspsqlserverreporting

The best thing is just to try it.  All you stand to lose is a couple of hours.  If it doesn't work, then you know they'll need to spring for a Professional Edition.

Comment: They also need to make sure they are following VS licensing terms here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/vs2022-ga-community/